# BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream) retorna null - Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Buenas!

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código en Android Studio:

```
try {
 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(dirPhoto);
 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream);
 vwImagen.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  } 
catch (SecurityException io){
} 
 catch (FileNotFoundException io) {
 }
```

El archivo fileInputStream parece crearse correctamente, pero al querer convertirlo en Bitmap la funcion `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream)` retorna un valor nulo.

Vale aclarar que es una imagen en jpg. El valor de dirPhoto es:

```
/data/data/com.example.leandro.application/files/pic_20170316104409.jpg
```

Gracias!

Comment: Revisa el LogCat que mensaje muestra, veo que tratas de escribir en el almacenamiento interno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes el path del archivo, puedes usar [**decodeFile()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String))

```
try {
 //FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(dirPhoto);
 //bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream);
  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dirPhoto);
 vwImagen.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  }catch (SecurityException io){
  }catch (FileNotFoundException io) {
 }
```

> [**decodeFile()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String)) Decodifica una ruta de archivo en un mapa de bits. Si el
>   nombre de archivo especificado es nulo o no se puede decodificar en un
>   mapa de bits, la función devuelve null.

Comment: El problema radicaba en que por alguna razon el FileInputStream no podia decodificar la direccion contenida en dirPhoto (aunque esta existiera). Lo solucioné creando la direccion con el metodo: "myContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()".

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

### Te recomiendo declararlo de esta manera:

*bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dirPhoto);*

vwImagen.setImageBitmap(bitmap);